# Convert a dataframe to string

Tags: python, dataframe

This code cannot run with the claim that itannot operate with a datframe but a string...

```
import tempfile
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
sav = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table",conn)
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(suffix=".csv") as d:
    with open(d + ".csv", "w") as stats:
        stats.write(sav)
        (...use stats..)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

How do I convert or rearrange the code to work?

Comment: @Sushanth. That's what I have there.

Comment: I think you want [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: I want it to temporary file....Use the temporary file to work out something then delete.

Comment: `sav.to_csv(stats)`?

Answer (score 0):

As 0x5453 metioned, pandas has own function to save data to csv file.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

There are also other extensions like json etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these options worked for me.

Comment: Would you explain why?